# How do I download iCloud-Photos to my iPhone?

Tags: icloud, photos, iphone

I use an iPhone 6s plus with 128 Gb memory. When I am on the road, I don't want to use mobile data to download photos or videos that are in the cloud, but I still want to view them. 
Is there a way to download all or a selection of my iCloud-content on my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the procedure of transferring photos from PC to iPhone.

1. Head to iCloud.com. Simply open your browser, navigate to iCloud.com and log in with your Apple ID.
2. Access your Photo Library. Once you’ve logged in to the iCloud website, click the Photos icon on the top row of apps. And if this is the first time you’ve accessed your Photo library from a browser, you’ll have to go through a first time setup.
3. Select photos to add to your photo library and iPhone. Once you’ve opened the Photos app and accessed your Photos library, there should be an “Upload” icon in the upper right hand corner of the page. Click this, and browse your PC for the photos you want to add to your iPhone.